# How to rewrite the code to use Kotlin's kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8?

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous

How to rewrite this code using Kotlin jdk async functions to avoid the error "Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body"?

```
    var result: CompletableFuture<CarInfoDto>? = null
try {
    result = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync {
        runBlocking {
            myService.getCarInfo(carId)  //**"Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body"**
        }
    }
    return ResponseEntity(future?.get(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), HttpStatus.OK)
} catch (timeoutException: TimeoutException) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The `get()` call in your current code blocks the current thread to wait for the asynchronous job, so there is no benefit in starting this async job in the first place, you can simply call `runBlocking` (and use `withTimeout` if you're actually interested in the timeout):

```kotlin
try {
    val result = runBlocking {
       withTimeout(1000) {
          myService.getCarInfo(carId)
       }
    }
    return ResponseEntity(result, HttpStatus.OK)
} catch (timeoutException: TimeoutException) {
    ...
}
```

However, since you seem to be using Spring, you should be able to make your controller function a `suspend` function, and you may not need to create a new coroutine or block at all (just call your `getCarInfo()` method).